# Dynamically add and remove stylesheets to the DOM

Tags: javascript, css

I have a continuously crowing block of elements like this :

```
<span class="widget">
    <div class="field-1"></div >
    <div class="field-2"></div >
    <div class="field-3"></div >
</span>
```

Depending on the users workflow I need to disable some of the `<div>` and enable them later again. So the user can see and access them or not.
This is easily achieved by CSS `display:block` and `display:none`.

As long I have only some of these `<span>` blocks around, I can switch the `<div>` on and off in a simple javascript loop. So far so good. But when the amount of blocks is growing to an arbitrary number this approach doesn't make sense.

So I learned that one can switch on and of complete stylesheets. See an example [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript).
Now before I start to dive into this advanced technic I have this question :

When I add and remove stylesheets to the DOM, will their attributes get applied immediatly ?
In other words can I use this approach to hide and show a complete set of elements in a page ?

Comment: You do not need stylesheets for thath, just use javascript.

Comment: For this you should simply use classes. Loading stylesheets separately is not recommended. Also, your `divs` are invalid in the provided code.

Comment: @Miguel - thats what I stated above. As long as there are some minor blocks around it´s no problem, but when you have hundred of them and you have to disable / enable hundreds of them in a javascript loop it will become a speed problem.

Comment: @somethinghere - thanks for your hint of the invalid div. This is an example, but I corrected it.

Comment: @Ben the thing is, it will _not_ be a speed problem if you only have to add a single class to a `parent` (or just the `body`) and let CSS take it from there. See the answer below, its very well informed.

Answer (score 2):

> When I add and remove stylesheets to the DOM, will their attributes get applied immediatly ?

Yes.

> In other words can I use this approach to hide and show a complete set of elements in a page ?

You *can*, but you almost certainly don't *want* to.

To control the styling of an entire set of elements, the easiest thing to do is define a rule that matches the elements you want to affect, and then do something that enables/disables that rule. In your case, for instance, you can make all `div` elements within your `span class="widget"` hidden by defining:

```
span.hide-divs div {
    display: none;
}
```

...and then adding/removing that class to the containing `span` as necessary.

Here's an example of a `div` containing a bunch of spans, where adding/removing a class on the divs hides/shows the spans:

```js
document.querySelector(".stuff").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("hide-spans");
}, false);
```

```css
div.stuff.hide-spans span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="stuff">
  <em>Click the div to toggle (this isn't a span, so it won't get hidden)</em>
  <span>span one</span>
  <span>span two</span>
  <span>span three</span>
</div>
```

**Note:** That example uses `classList`, which may require a shim on older browsers. It also uses `addEventListener`, which isn't supported on IE8 and earlier. That's just to keep it brief.

---

Side note: It's invalid to have `div` as a direct child of `span`. [The content model of `span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) is [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1), but [context where `div` can be used](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) is [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1).

Comment: When I got you right , I simply need to define a class which I can toggle on and off as you stated ?

Comment: I accept this answer though I can not use it due to this [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)

Comment: @Ben: That's just one way to add/remove classes, and it can be shimmed.